# How to create a temporary directory for a feature in python's behave (cucumber)?

Tags: python, cucumber, python-behave

I'm trying to do a python port of some ruby code that uses [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/?lang=ruby) for testing.  I'm attempting to use the exact same feature files in the new port.  One of the features looks a bit like:

```
Feature: <whatever>

@with_tmpdir
Scenario: generating a file
  Given <some setup stuff>
    And file 'test.out' does not exist
   When I call <something> with argument 'test.out'
   Then a file called 'test.out' is created
    And the file called 'test.out' contains:
      """
      <some contents>
      """
```

To support this, the original code has the following in `features/support/hooks.rb`:

```rb
Around('@with_tmpdir') do |scenario, block|
  old_pwd = Dir.getwd
  Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|
    Dir.chdir(dir)
    block.call
  end
  Dir.chdir(old_pwd)
end
```

Now, I'd like to figure out how to do this sort of thing in [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), presumably/ideally utilizing [`with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory as tmpdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory) in place of ruby's [`Dir.mktmpdir do |dir|`](https://ruby-doc.org/current/stdlibs/tmpdir/Dir.html#method-c-mktmpdir).

Alas, I don't see anything to indicate support for `Around` hooks.  It seems like maybe this is the sort of thing that [fixtures](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures/?highlight=fixtures) are meant to do?  Can fixtures do what I'm hoping for?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, fixtures can be used to get the behavior you're looking for.  To wit, you could add the following code to `features/environment.py`, and it should do the trick:

```py
from behave import fixture, use_fixture
from tempfile import TemporaryDirectory
from os import getcwd, chdir

@fixture
def with_tmpdir(context, **kwargs):
  old_pwd = getcwd()
  with TemporaryDirectory() as tmpdir:
    chdir(tmpdir)
    yield
  chdir(old_pwd)

# note: maybe re-tag as fixture.with_tmpdir ?
def before_tag(context, tag):
  if tag == 'with_tmpdir':
    use_fixture(with_tmpdir, context)
```

As a side-note, and indicated in a comment above, the normal convention in behave is for the tags for fixtures to be called `fixture.<something>`.  Per the docs:

> Fixture tags should start with `"@fixture.*"` prefix to improve readability and understandibilty in feature files (Gherkin).

That said, I left the code to react to the feature file as you present it, since you state you're hoping to use the same file, presumably unchanged.